# Evaluate the line integral $\int_\gamma \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy + \ln{(z^4+z^2+1)}dz$ using Stokes' Theorem

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I found the following problem in a textbook (translated):

> Evaluate $$\int_\gamma \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy + \ln{(z^4+z^2+1)}dz$$ where $\;\gamma\;$ is given by the intersection between the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$, and the plane $x+y+10z=10$. The orientation is chosen to be so that the curve goes one revolution around the $z$-axis clockwise (seen from above)

I am thinking to use stokes theorem. I evaluate the curl to be $(0,0,0)$ and the line integral becomses $0$. I know this is incorrect, what am I missing? I also see that the vector field is undefined along the $z$-axis.

Comment: I also get curl $F = 0$.  But Stokes' Theorem requires the vector field have continuous partial derivatives on an open region in$ R^3$ that contains the entire surface.  As you say, the vector field is not defined on $z=0$, so Stokes' Theorem does not apply.

Comment: How do you go about solving such a problem then? Usually I would try to paramterize the the curve but I don't see how it would simplify the integral.

Comment: The question says using Stokes theorem. Stokes theorem does not say that your surface can have only one boundary. So it is easiest to choose surface with two boundaries and to simplify working, we make use of the fact that curl is zero. Please see my answer and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor just reading your comment, it is not correct to say that Stokes' theorem does not apply. Line integral of the vector field over the boundary curve is equal to the surface integral of the curl of the vector field over any surface with the same boundary curve provided the vector field is continuously differentiable over the entire surface. So we must choose the surface carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the vector field is not defined at any point on z-axis, it will be easiest to choose surface of the cone between $z = 1 - \frac{1}{10} (x + y)$  and say $z = 2$ [any value of $z (\ne 0)$ which intersects the cone and is clear from the other plane $x+y+10z = 10$ within the bounds of the cone]. Now our surface has two boundaries.

So by Stokes theorem we have,

$\displaystyle \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \hat {n} \ dS = 0 = \int_{C2} \vec F \ dr - \int_{C1} \vec F \ dr$

$\displaystyle - \int_{C1} \vec F \ dr = - \int_{C2} \vec F \ dr$

where $C1$ is the curve given by intersection of $x+y+10z = 10$ and $z^2 = x^2+y^2$. $C2$ is intersection of plane $z = 2, z^2 = x^2+y^2$.

We parametrize curve $C2$ as $ \ r(t) = (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t, 2)$

$r'(t) = (-2\sin t, 2 \cos t, 0)$

$\vec F (r(t))= (- \frac{2 \sin t}{4}, \frac{2 \cos t}{4}, \ln (21))$

$\displaystyle - \int_{C2} \vec F \ dr = - \int_0^{2\pi} \vec F(r(t)) \cdot r'(t) \ dt = - 2\pi$

Comment: I didn't quite follow that trick.  You're changing the surface into one with a hole in it and two boundaries, but I didn't follow where your other boundary is or how you found its integral to be zero.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor The surface integral over the surface of the cone between two boundaries is zero as the curl of the vector field is zero. One of the boundaries is given in the question. I am choosing the second boundary as intersection of cone and plane $z = k$. Now we know it is difficult to  find line integral over the first boundary. So instead we find line integral over second boundary.

Comment: I chose $k = 2$, we could as well choose $k = 10$.

Comment: Aha, beautiful! I see how this solves the problem, but how would someone justify/come up with using two boundaries when initially approching the problem?

Comment: @alibakly thank you. Just to understand your question better, are you asking what is the intuition behind choosing surface with two boundaries?

Comment: @MathLover yes!

Comment: sorry was away. For the given boundary curve, which is around z-axis, we need to choose a surface that does not cross z-axis or touch z-axis. That is only possible if the surface has two boundary curves around z-axis. So one possible option is part of the given cone.

Answer (score 1):

As @RobertTheTutor notes, you need a different strategy. In fact you thought of one, but let me show how it works. Give $\gamma$ [the parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions)$$x=r\cos\varphi,\,y=r\sin\varphi,\,\pm r=z=1-r(\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi)/10$$so $r=\frac{\pm10}{10\pm(\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi)}$. In fact the $\pm$ must be $+$ since $r\ge0$, so$$x=\frac{10\cos\varphi}{10+\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi},\,y=\frac{10\sin\varphi}{10+\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi},\,z=\frac{10}{10+\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi}.$$Hence $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}+\ln(z^4+z^2+1)dz$ is $d\varphi$ times a function of $\varphi$ you can integrate from $2\pi$ to $0$ to get the desired orientation (if I've read the instructions correctly). The $z$ part will of course just give us $0$ by periodicity, but the first term is just $d\varphi$, making the answer $-2\pi$. That the result is a multiple of $2\pi$ won't surprise anyone familiar with the effect poles have on contour integrals in complex analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Since the vector field is not defined on the entire surface, we cannot use Stokes' Theorem, so we must perform the line integral directly.

We parametrize the curve: $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$, with $x = \cos t, y = \sin t, z = 1-\frac{1}{10}(\cos t + \sin t)$

$$\int \overrightarrow F \cdot d\overrightarrow r = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{-\sin t}{\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t}\cdot(-\sin t) +\frac{\cos t}{\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t}\cdot(\cos t) dt + \int\ln (z^4 + z^2 + 1)dz $$ which simplifies to $$2\pi + \int\ln (z^4 + z^2 + 1)dz $$ where $z = 1-\frac{1}{10}(\cos t + \sin t)$.

Integrating by parts, I find
$$\int \ln (z^4 + z^2 + 1) dz = z\ln(z^4 + z^2 + 1)|_{t=0}^{t=2\pi} - \int \frac{z(4z^3+2z)}{z^4+z^2 + 1}dz =  - \int \frac{z(4z^3+2z)}{z^4+z^2 + 1}dz $$ from here it looks like a straightforward slog through long division and partial fractions, since $z^4 + z^2 + 1 = z^4 + 2z^2 + 1 - z^2 = (z^2 + 1)^2 - z^2 = (z^2 + 1 + z)(z^2 + 1 -z)$.

EDIT: Actually, since $z$ is a periodic function of $t$ with period $2\pi$, integrating from $0$ to $2\pi$ $dt$ should give $0$ for the entire $z$ integral, leaving the answer $2\pi$.
EDIT2: And don't forget a minus sign because it is clockwise, not counterclockwise, so the answer is $-2\pi$.